# Deleting partial duplicates in a list of strings/floats of size >1

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to delete some "partial duplicates" (some positions in a tuple may match) in a list of primarily string inputs.  This would be some samples from the list

```
[['Dave', '1'],
['Dave', '2'],
['Dave', '3'],
['Dave', '4'],
['Jack Jones', '5'],
['Joaquin', '6'],
['Joaquin', '7'],
['Joaquin', '8']]
```

Now, I'd like to delete every row in this list where the element in the first position matches the proceeding row's first positional element like so:

```
[['Dave', '1'],
['Jack Jones', '5'],
['Joaquin', '6']]
```

I have tried going about this as I would when considering an array object with numerical data-but I think I'm misusing objects where I shouldn't be.

```
def duplicate_remover(x):
    dupesremoved = []

    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] != x[i-1]:
            dupesremoved.append(x[i])
```

Comment: Give us actual sample data to work with (formatted as compilable python)

Comment: `x[i] != x[i]` is always `False`. what's the point of posting code like that? what's with the `numpy` tag?

Comment: What is 'tabular form'?  That's not a real Python data structure.

Comment: I wasn't sure how I should have provided the data, I'll edit in the proper format

I also made a typo in that line.  My bad.  (I also wasn't sure if I should tag numpy or not)

Comment: @user7351362 Well generally, you want to provide your input so that lazy programmers can answer your question whilst wasting as little time as possible creating classes to fit your data, and then formatting it into a proper structure.

Comment: yeah that's my bad.  I wasn't sure if I should have said "These are strings arranged like so" or if I should have just chucked the input directly from my console.  I'll make sure to do that in the future.

Comment: if you don't think `x[i] != x[i-1]` is correct then check what those actually are, you are close but no that would only remove entries that are exact duplicates (both values are same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), however the actual approach might differ depending on your actual input format:

```
it = [
    ['Dave', '1'],
    ['Dave', '2'],
    ['Dave', '3'],
    ['Dave', '4'],
    ['Jack Jones', '5'],
    ['Joaquin', '6'],
    ['Joaquin', '7'],
    ['Joaquin', '8'],
]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

for first, group in groupby(it, key=itemgetter(0)):
    print(next(group))
```

which prints:

```
['Dave', '1']
['Jack Jones', '5']
['Joaquin', '6']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I went ahead and pasted the formatting from the value  column in my variable explorer for additional clarity.

Comment: @user7351362 I removed the second example but the first example should work with your example. :)

Comment: thank you very much!  did my edit help out/conform to proper formatting, or was it still kinda ambiguous?

Some other replies were concerned with that and it's something I should work on.

thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user7351362 The new version is definetly better than the original. Does the answer solve your problem? If so please consider to accept it, otherwise let me know what doesn't work :)

Comment: just saw your newest comment and accepted!  thanks for all your help